# SonarQube: Unrecoverable indexation failures

Tags: sonarqube, sonarqube-scan

I'm using SonarQube as a static code analyzer tool and it was working fine. Suddenly it started giving this error - Unrecoverable indexation failures.

I have checked the Sonar log and from es.log I can see this error -

> 2020.05.13 12:04:25 WARN  es[][o.e.c.r.a.DiskThresholdMonitor] high disk watermark [90%] exceeded on
>   [tsxLSmcQQn2gUd1KfwDGmg][sonarqube][C:\sonarqube-7.8\data\es6\nodes\0]
>   free: 10.2gb[5.1%], shards will be relocated away from this node

It seems some space issue but since  I have 10 GB space left then why it is causing an issue.

How this issue can be fixed without increasing the Hard disk space.

Answer (score 0):

I also meet this error, and my disk has 10GB space left.
then I restart sonarqube, question has solved.

but es.log still has WARN log.

So I think increasing disk space is the only way...
or you can use Treesize.exe to find and delete some unusing file.